# Ex husbands email contacts showing on my email contact list

Tags: icloud

I have just discovered that my ex husband's email contacts are on my email contact list. I contacted Apple and they said our accounts aren't linked but from what I have since been reading, it seems that we might be sharing an icloud account that I'm not aware of. How can I find out if this is the case please. We've been apart for five years but I have recently had on line security issues

Comment: in iOS 11 your iCloud account is the first thing you see in the settings app. In macOS 10.13, you can see it under Settings>iCloud. What type of computer are you using?

Comment: Sorry it's taken so long to respond. I have a Mac but my ex's email contacts do not appear on the Mac they are only on my iPhone and since I first posted my question, more have appeared. Any help would be good thank you

Comment: As dwightk observed, the iCloud account your phone is connected to shows up in Settings. Is the account that's shown on your phone unfamiliar to you? If it is unfamiliar, sign out of it.